# unable to configure leaks instrument for target process

Tags: iphone, objective-c, instruments

Hi I am getting unable to configure leaks instrument for target process when i try to run the performance tool with my app on a simulator. any ideas? I have the last xcode version. Thanks. I never had this problem before. I noticed this after updating my xcode.

Comment: I sorted it out. had to manually change the target. looks like the xcode update messed my stuff.

Comment: Hmm actually I still get some weird issues and need to restart xcode everytime i want to use the perfomance tool.

Comment: What did you exactly changed in your project target?

Comment: restarted it and removed the entitlements.plist , and also cleaned all targets.

Answer (score 24):

Try disconnecting your iPad/iPhone. Having the device connected while running the Simulator seems to confuse Instruments. (Xcode 3.2.3)